# Where can I find gang members after the game ends?

Tags: crackdown

After the main story ends, city police occupy the places where the gang leaders once were and I cannot find gang members anywhere. Are there some places where a bunch of them still spawn after the game ends (without having to go to a different mode like Time Trials)?

Comment: On the 360 at least, a update let you re-animate the gangs iirc. It's been a long time since I played, so maybe that was only in the second game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there used to be a "Crimes on" option, but it was modified by a later patch.  Per [this Gamefaqs thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/930144-crackdown/43393001), it is possible to spawn individual gangs by selecting options from the start menu, after beating the game.

> After the patch you can respawn the gangs on the starting menu where you pick your agent and the difficulty. When you go to launch campaign,press right and it gives the option to respawn the gangs.

Comment: Thanks. There is an option to "Resurrect Gangs" as you quoted, but I believe that's irreversible. I'm looking to stay within the same game.